# Did I install rails on local host properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to begin developing my first Rails App and I'm having difficulty with getting started. I was watching this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GY7Ps8fqGdc) and stopped at the 4:27 mark.

I wrote this code here:
$ rails new readit -d mysql

And this error message below showed up:
VM573:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (:694:21)

Do I need to install RailsInstaller into my Local host inorder to be able to move forward?
Is that even the issue here?

Comment: That looks like a code bug. Cause if rails isn't installed correctly it throws up way different bugs. Also is readit correct? I haven't seen that before, did you mean reddit?

Answer (score 0):

I would try it without the `$`. So on the command line put in `rails new readit -d mysql`.

You can also tell if you have rails installed by using `rails -v` and it should tell you what version you have.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it but it didn't work. I'm going to use nitrous.io instead. Since, I have a Windows machine, I hear there's a couple steps I have to go through to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

It might be something about the installation of mysql. You have to install mysql yourself.
If you do not want mysql try

```
rails new readit
```

If you want mysql, then add `gem 'mysql2'` to the **Gemfile** and run `bundle install` after the `rails new` command

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it but it didn't work. I'm going to use nitrous.io instead. Since, I have a Windows machine, I hear there's a couple steps I have to go through to set it up.

Comment: Aah. so its a windows machine. When I read the `$` in the `rails new` command I thought it was linux. Sorry